# Is there a geometry behind the singularity formation in solutions to nonlinear ODE's?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, curvature, symplectic-geometry, contact-geometry

**Disclaimer:** I have posted this question on [mathoverflow.net](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/408133/are-there-a-geometry-behind-the-singularity-formation-in-solutions-to-nonlinear) following the instructions of [this topic](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2637/cross-posts-to-math-se/2638#2638).

---

If we take two apparently simple first order ODE's like $y'=y$ and $y'=y^2$ we find that:

For the first one the general solution is $y=C\exp(t)$ and is defined for all $t$.

For the second one, the general solution is $y=\frac{1}{C-t}$ and it's defined only for $t<C$.

There is a way to 'see' geometrically the solutions of these equations as leaves of the "Characteristic Foliation" of the standard contact structure of $R^3$. Look at [this site](https://www.imo.universite-paris-saclay.fr/%7Epmassot/en/exposition/gallerie_contact/xiS/)
and [this article](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Earchristian/notes/gallery.pdf) for some nice pictured examples.

Looking for the characteristic foliation of the two equations, the shape of the surface seens to play a big role. Apparently is the curvature of the surface that, somehow, 'controls' the growth of solutions.

**My question is:** Are there some notion of curvature that explains why nonlinear EDO's can have solutions with movable singularities?

I know that Contact geometry doesn't have local invariants as Riemannian geometry, so, I believe, the answer to this question lies beyond the domain of Contact/Symplectic geometry.

**ps:** taking other linear and nonlinear equations, with or without time varying coeficients, I had the same impression.

Here are some pictures that I made:

Characteristic foliation for $y'=y$
[image: y'=y]

Characteristic foliation for $y'=y^2$
[image]